# TypeError at /blog/feed/ 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, rss

I am implementing blog app from the book Django by example. Upto chapter 2 it worked fine but when I try to implement rss feed, it gave the following error when I run my browser:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/feed/    
Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'] 

Traceback:

File "d:\virEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "d:\virEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "d:\virEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\syndication\views.py" in __call__
  41.         feedgen = self.get_feed(obj, request)

File "d:\virEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\syndication\views.py" in get_feed
  169.         for item in self.__get_dynamic_attr('items', obj):

Exception Type: TypeError at /blog/feed/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**This is my feeds.py:**

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatewords
from .models import Post

class LatestPostsFeed(Feed):
    title = 'My blog'
    link = '/blog/'
    description = 'New posts of my blog.'

def items(self):
    return Post.published.all()[:5]

def item_title(self, item):
    return item.title

def item_description(self, item):
    return truncatewords(item.body, 30)
```

**This is my url part:**

```
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed

url(r'^feed/$', LatestPostsFeed(), name='post_feed')
```

Why not work this code in my browser? Previously I installed markdown==2.6.6. Does it causes any hindrance?

EDIT:My views.py file:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.core.paginator import (Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger)

from django.views.generic import ListView

from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from .models import Post, Comment
from taggit.models import Tag

# Create your views here.

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'page': page,
                            'posts': posts,
                            'tag': tag})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
        status='published',
        publish__year=year,
        publish__month=month,
        publish__day=day)

    # List of active comments for this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A comment was posted
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

     # List of similar posts
    post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
    similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
                                    .exclude(id=post.id)
    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                                    .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]

    return render(request,
        'blog/post/detail.html',
        {'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
        'similar_posts': similar_posts,})

def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Retrieve post by id
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id,status='published')
    sent = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form was submitted
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form fields passed validation
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            # ... send email
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(          post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@example.com',[cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()

    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                            'form': form,
                                            'sent': sent,
                                          })
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct? If your post matches your code, then you'll need to indent at the definitions.

Comment: If you click the 'Switch to copy-and-paste view' button, it changes the traceback to a nicer format for posting here.

Comment: Please post the view.py, it's there that the error happens.

Comment: server not gave any indentation erros. I reposted traceback as Alasdair suggestion. I also post my view.py file. I hope now I will get the suggestions to fix it.